# Parenting in A* Pathfinding algorithm?

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, c++17, path-finding, a-star

So im trying to implement the A* pathfinding algorithm as a C++ program. I have most of it figured out, the algorithm eventually finds its way to end, but without creating other random unnecessary paths in the process, as shown below:

[image: S is starting node, E is end node, p is the path, and X are the walls to avoid]

S is starting node, E is end node, p is the path, and X are the walls to avoid.
When I trace back the path from the end node, through it's parents, it also includes
as parents all other nodes which don't lead to the end, but are technically closer, such as
node (2 , 3). My problem is under what conditions should a node be made a parent of the other? How do I ensure only the optimal path is traced back? Here is a snippet of the program of the recursive
function:

```
void Node::RecursiveScan(NodeMap &map) {

    this->ScanAdjacents(map.NodeMapContainer);

    for (auto &adjacentNode : this->AdjacentNodes) {
        cout << "start" << endl;
        cout << this->GetDistanceCost() << " " << this->distanceToEnd << " " << this->GetNodeCoords().first << " , " << this->GetNodeCoords().second << endl;
        if (adjacentNode->GetNodeType() != 1 && adjacentNode->nodeScanned == false) {
            adjacentNode->CalcDistances(map);
            adjacentNode->nodeScanned = true;
            map.ScannedNodes.emplace(adjacentNode);
        }
    }
    for (auto &scannedNode : map.ScannedNodes) { // ScannedNodes is an ordered multiset of shared ptrs (open set)
        if (scannedNode->GetNodeType() == 2 && *map.found == false) {
            *map.found = true;
            map.EndNode->ParentNode.reset(this);
            map.VisitedNodes.emplace(map.EndNode);
            return;
        }
        else if (scannedNode->GetNodeType() == 0 && *map.found == false && scannedNode->nodeVisited == false) {
            scannedNode->ParentNode.reset(this); // Parenting here
            scannedNode->nodeVisited = true;
            map.VisitedNodes.emplace(scannedNode); // VisitedNodes is an ordered multiset of shared ptrs (close set)
            scannedNode->RecursiveScan(map);
        }
}
}
```

The algorithm also works fine in simpler straight forward pathing:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You maintain a running sum of the path cost.  When you hit a node with a path cost that is lower than what it already contains, that is when you update the `parent`.  When the whole calculation is done, the `parent` chain should basically allow you to walk back from the destination node back to the start node.

When I have done routeing algorithms in the past I used a priority queue for providing the "next node" feed as opposed to using any kind of recursion (and applied the heuristics to the priority score in order to coax the preferred nodes to be popped first).

Comment: By path cost do you mean G cost, F cost, or H cost?

Comment: On the basis of f(n) = g(n) + h(n), it would be the "g" cost with no heuristics applied.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2A_search_algorithm

Comment: Also what would you base the order in the priority queue on? And in case two nodes' values are equal, what would you use as tie breaker?

Comment: Priority queue order would be the F cost.  If you used the G cost it would be equivalent to Dijkstra.  For the Priority Queue I don't think it matters if two nodes are equal, but if it does then use a sequence number or maybe even the node address.